# Flink task manager managed memory used is showing zero

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to tune memory configuration for my flink job deployed using FlinkKubernetesOperator. The job uses rocks db for state management.Following are the memory settings. I am configuring only Total memory as mentioned in this doc.
https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/memory/mem_setup_tm/

```
taskmanager.memory.process.size: "6000m"
taskmanager.memory.task.off-heap.size: "500m"
taskmanager.memory.jvm-metaspace.size: "250m" 
**state.backend.rocksdb.memory.managed: "false"**
state.backend.rocksdb.writebuffer.size: "512mb"
state.backend.rocksdb.block.cache-size: "128mb"
state.backend.rocksdb.block.blocksize: "64kb"
state.backend.rocksdb.writebuffer.count: "5"
state.backend.rocksdb.writebuffer.number-to-merge: "2"
state.backend.rocksdb.metrics.block-cache-usage: "true"
```

When the job starts processing, the metrics show that flink_taskmanager_Status_Flink_Memory_Managed_Used is always ZERO.
where flink_taskmanager_Status_Flink_Memory_Managed_Total is set to 2.1Gb.

Want to understand why managed memory used is showing as 0? (edited)

Comment: Hey I have encountered  the same problem did you find a solution?